Configuring Spring WebClient with Spring Cloud LoadBalancer: Resolving 'ROLE-SERVICE' Endpoint Issue
I'm currently seeking a web client solution for my Spring Boot application, which needs to establish connections with my microservices. The application is configured to utilize Eureka service discovery and requires load balancing capabilities via Spring Cloud LoadBalancer.
However, I'm encountering some confusion regarding the handling of Spring Cloud LoadBalancer. Below, I've outlined my configuration for multiple web clients:
@Configuration
@LoadBalancerClients({
    @LoadBalancerClient(name = "ROLE-SERVICE", configuration = LoadBalancerConfiguration.class),
    @LoadBalancerClient(name = "USER-SERVICE", configuration = LoadBalancerConfiguration.class)
})
public class WebClientConfig {    

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient webClientUserService() {
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl("http://USER-SERVICE")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient webClientRoleService() {
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .baseUrl("http://ROLE-SERVICE")
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
}

My LoadBalancerConfiguration looks like this:
@Configuration
public class LoadBalancerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServiceInstanceListSupplier discoveryClientServiceInstanceListSupplier(
            ConfigurableApplicationContext context) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier.builder()
                .withDiscoveryClient()
                .withSameInstancePreference()                
                .build(context);
    }
}

In my business logic, I utilize the WebClient as follows:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ShopService {

    private final WebClient webClientRoleService;    

    @Value("${messages.default-error-message}")
    private String DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE;

    Gson gson = new Gson();
   
    public Mono<ChatMessage> sendMessage(
            ChatMessage userMessage,
            String iss) {

        return webClientRoleService
                .get()
                .uri("/roles")
                .header("iss", iss)
                .header("userID", userMessage.getUserID())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class);                
    }
}

In some tutorials, I noticed that the URL is created with webClient.uri("http://ROLE-SERVICE/roles"). However, I prefer setting the BaseURL in my WebClient configuration because I require a different configuration for testing in my JUnit tests.
The instances of my microservices are correctly displayed in the admin panel of Eureka:
eureka:
  instance:
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.uuid}
    prefer-ip-address: true
  client:
    healthcheck:
      enabled: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true

When I execute my code, I encounter an error stating that "ROLE-SERVICE" could not be resolved. What am I doing wrong here?
2024-04-14T10:27:01.634+02:00 ERROR 12932 --- [kosmo-backend] [nio-8088-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Failed to resolve 'ROLE-SERVICE' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries ] with root cause

java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'ROLE-SERVICE' [A(1), AAAA(28)] after 6 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1120) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1067) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:440) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:670) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$500(DnsResolveContext.java:68) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:497) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:625) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:105) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:338) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finishSuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:329) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1387) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:97) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) ~[netty-transport-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.105.Final.jar:4.1.105.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]


I have faced the same issue, and after trying to fix it. this is the solution.

first you must create an implementation from ServiceInstanceListSupplier to register your service into the spring cloud load balancer webclient.this approach will provide a list of IP to register into ServiceInstanceListSupplier that get from eureka discoveryclient.

public class ServiceInstanceListSupplierLoadBalancer implements ServiceInstanceListSupplier {

    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;
    private final String serviceId;

    public ServiceInstanceListSupplierLoadBalancer(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient, String serviceId) {
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
        this.serviceId = serviceId;
    }


    @Override
    public String getServiceId() {
        return serviceId;
    }

    @Override
    public Flux<List<ServiceInstance>> get() {
        // Fetch the service instances from the DiscoveryClient
        List<ServiceInstance> instances = discoveryClient.getInstances(serviceId);
        return Flux.just(instances);
    }
}


the second step create a LoadBalancer configuration for your service, this approach make your webclient to know what service that must pick or use from load balancer list supplier instance.

public class RoleAuthorityWebclientConfiguration {

    private final DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

    public RoleAuthorityWebclientConfiguration(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient) {
        this.discoveryClient = discoveryClient;
    }

    @Bean
    ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier() {
        return new ServiceInstanceListSupplierLoadBalancer(discoveryClient,"rolesauthority-ws");
    }
}


the final step create a webclient builder that will be use soon for HTTP call to another service.

@Configuration
@LoadBalancerClient(name="rolesauthority-ws",configuration = RoleAuthorityWebclientConfiguration.class)
public class WebClientRoleAuthorityService {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced // Apply the annotation to the builder, not the WebClient instance
    public WebClient.Builder roleAuthorityServiceWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://rolesauthority-ws/");
    }
}

note don't forget to add baseUrl for eg : http://rolesauthority-ws/ and must be user HTTP://.
Hopefully, this approach can be helpful.
